# unable to open external url through php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, curl

I am using a bulk sms service , in order to send the sms I need to open the following url in my php file .

```
$url="transsms.bulksms5.com/sendmessage.php?user=".urlencode($username)."&password=".urlencode($password)."
&mobile=".urlencode($phone)."&message=".urlencode($message)."&sender=".urlencode($sender)."&type=".urlencode('3');
```

I tried echoing this url and tried to post the url with ajax, but that is just appending the url to the current path.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxRegisterSMS.php",
            data: { .........},
             success: function(response1) { //url that has been echoed
                 alert(response1);
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: response1,
                    data:{},
                    success : function(){
                        alert("SMS sent");
                    }
                    });
             }
        });
```

This didnt work, i also tried using curl , but since i am using 000webhost i dont have access to the server to install the necessary library

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

`file_get_contents($url)` threw an error saying function not found

When I copy the url and open it in the browser it works fine, just that i want php to the same

Comment: Are you sure that curl is not installed? What I know about 000webhost is they block outbound calls on port 80. Perhaps update your url to use https (usually port 443) to see if that gets through. Run this to see if curl is actually installed: `echo function_exists('curl_init') ? 'curl is installed.':'Curl is not installed.';`

Comment: Yes @webCode , from the 000webhost forum I found out that port 80 Is disabled, but how do I update to Https? The sms provider is insecure.

Comment: If the sms service provider supports https then just prepend https:// onto the url and see if that works.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work...

Comment: That url is missing the `http://` in front. Thats why ajax just appends it to the current url. Also why curl would error, and why file_get_contents would not 'find that file' (there is no such thing as file_get_contents ***function*** does not exist unless you are running php3). And when you copy it to a browser, the browser is automatically adding the `http://` in front since you left it off.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, pre pending http:// would have worked , but my site is https , thats blocking it form loading. pre pending https:// doesnt work

Comment: @WebCode.ie , curl is installed , but i dont know why its not able to access the url

Comment: If your php is calling the url with either curl or file_get_contents (with fopen url wrappers enabled)... it doesn't matter if YOUR site is https or not. PHP executes on the server, directly to the url you are trying to reach. If you do not formulate a proper url, then you will get nowhere. You cannot do it with ajax, even if you have it right due to cross domain policy and also insecure resource content (browser security). Your only way to do this, is with the php end. You may need to get a better host that doesn't have a gimped php install.

Comment: @IncredibleHat i used file_get_contents($url). adding http:// to the url returns invalid user. without http:// it is taking it as a relative path and appending. any particular syntax you'd suggest?